# Unity Multiplayer Cube Auto Move?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have followed the Unity official Multiplayer Guide below and everything works, except for the fact that when I run two instances on the same computer (1 in build run and the other in the play mode) the characters for some reason auto move in a circle.

I have no idea why this is since I have followed the tutorial exactly, unless I missed something :P   I am currently on step 9 (identifying local player) and I stopped there cause my players keep moving in circles.

To Clarify, they aren't spinning in place, they are walking in a circle. Just imagine a person following a dotted circle on the floor, same idea.

This issue only happens when i run two instances (build run mode and play mode in unity). if i try only the play mode in unity, everything works fine.

Has anyone experienced this before?

***Unity Multiplayer Tutorial***: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/network-manager?playlist=29690

I am on version 2017.2.0f3    <-- maybe this is why? should I update to a different patch?

Thank you in advance

Where I spawn the characters
[image: Where I spawn the characters]

build and run, player just moves in circles automatically
[image: build and run, player just spins in circles automatically]

both build run and play mode, they both again moves in circles automatically
[image: both build run and play mode, they both again spin in circles automatically]

Comment: "the characters for some reason auto move to the top left"... Can you post a screenshot of what is happening ? Where do you spawn your players ? https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/spawning-and-respawning?playlist=29690

Comment: @PierreBaret, Thank you for trying to help me with my issue. Also, to correct myself i meant "moving in a circle", I was looking at another build of a similar concept. I have updated my info to match the tutorial exactly. I have uploaded some screen shots and have added more info above. I would upload vid or a GIF if I knew how to make those and upload them here.

Comment: @PierreBaret I forgot to mention, the auto circular movements only happens when i have two instances run. if i just use the play mode in unity, everything is fine. If i run both build run mode and play mode (doesn't matter which one is host), the players move in a circle

Comment: Regarding the camera, there is nothing to network the camera in this tutorial so it is normal: the camera is fixed to the center of the screen. You think the players are moved to the top left because you use a small window for your build and because of the GUI element. Try launch the build in a bigger window, you'll see that the players are in fact just centered to the middle of the screen.

Comment: Regarding player movement, to make sure only one player move, go throught part 07 of the tuto: https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/networking-player-movement?playlist=29690

Comment: @PierreBaret To answer your first response: it is not that the camera shows the players near top left, the players are actually moving on their own without me hitting any keys. For your second response: I have checked the code and went through part 7 many times and everything matches. Unless I am blind, there is nothing different from my version the and tutorial.

Comment: @PierreBaret Can I somehow share my project with you?

Comment: yes I went through all of it. Indeed it would be usefull to see your code. Do you have it on a GitHub?

Comment: @PierreBaret Sorry I do not, I could however zip this entire project (very small) and send it over email. would this be ok? I can also snapchat this "circular movement" to you If you like.

Comment: @PierreBaret Ok, I have sent the email. The subject is "Unity MP Issue"  from kevin-d@hotmail.com.  Please respond back here as I do not check my email very often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a first issue in your code:

PlayerController.cs line 36, you wrote

```
   var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(BulletPrefab, BulletSpawn.transform.position, BulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
```

it should be

```
   var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(BulletPrefab, BulletSpawn.position, BulletSpawn.rotation);
```

Since BulletSpawn is already a Transform. Otherwise bullets might not fire in the gun direction.

I don't have any of the player moving without me pressing keybord key.

Here is a screenshot of 2 build run working good:
[image]

I also tried Build run + Unity Editor in game mode, I had no problem.

Maybe the problem comes from your keyboard or the input manager of unity ? Since you are using `Input.GetAxis`, check this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html

Comment: Have you tried file -build run? the player movement only happens to me during either:

1 instance of build run - host game

OR

2 instances (1 build run and other is through the play mode in unity)

Comment: I just edited my answer, I can confirm I don't have the moving behavior you described with the code you sent me.

Comment: I will try this project on another computer and see what happens. mind telling me which version of unity you are using?

Comment: Thank you, I will give you answer check mark on this. Btw do you know the difference between versions 2017 and 5.6? I am new to unity and I don't get this

Comment: Thanks, I hope I was of any help on this. I don't know exactly all the new changes. For what i'm doing with Unity 5.6 or 2017 doesn't change anything. It looks like they didn't anything on the Networking components since 5.3 btw. You can find the sources of those components here : https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src/5.3/Runtime/

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your character automatically moving is because you have something plugged into your computer that acts as a controller/joytick. Go into settings for controls and set all joystick to the last joystick #. Make sure you set this for all vertical and horizontal movement. That should do the trick.

For example, if you use a 3D mouse like 3D connexion, it could act as a joystick/controller and auto move your character.